# How to iterate over dictionary subitems with multiple different items in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I was interested in finding out how to set up a vars file with the following structure and how to iterate multiple deeply nested items in a dictionary.  The end goal is to have a task performed on hosts that match a multiple or single roles or are used by a particular team, or teams.

1. Is this structure correct? I have seen so many different examples, I'm not sure anymore...
2. Is it possible in ansible to perhaps perform a task on multiple hosts by matching a single role but matching multiple teams?
3. How can I iterate through the dictionary and get an individual item from within a subelement that has multiple items, like "teams: sales"  or "teams: dev" ?  For example, I'd like to perform the task on host1 and matching operation and dev and sales teams files I have available for them.  For example, copy a file to a team directory on that one host.  Host2 has different teams and therefore the same task could be used but deliver the file to only those team directories on that single host.
4. The same desire would apply to the role of each host...  being able to have multiple roles for a single host but matching on the role value (either both roles or a single role).

Anyhow, I've looked at a lot of things and I haven't quite found something that fits this but I feel it is possible -- sorta??

```
### hostmap.yml

---
host_team_map:
  host_list:
    host1:
      comment: "host description"
      application_role: [ 'role1', 'role2' ]  <----------- multiple subitems
      teams: [ 'operations', 'dev', 'sales' ]    <----------- multiple subitems
    host2:
      comment: "host description"
      application_role: [ 'role3' ]
      teams: [ 'operations', 'dev' ]
    host3:
      comment: "host description"
      application_role: [ 'role3', 'role4' ]
      teams: [ 'operations' ]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear from your question what it is you're trying to do, but looking at your `hostmap.yml` file it looks like that should just be an inventory file.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand well, you want to apply the list of roles for an host, and from this role, only a part of tasks based on the teams elements.

If it is the case, then you may have, for each role, a task file with the name of the teams and use the include_role module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html

Here is an example of what you may do:

1) As @larsks suggest, you should put necessary vars in the inventory (thus, having `application_role` an `teams`  specific for "current" host)
For example, in `host_vars`:

```
### host1.yml
---
application_role:
  - role1
  - role2
  - ...
teams:
  - dev
  - operation
  - ...
```

2) Role directory structure example:

```
roles/
  role1/
    tasks/
      operation.yml
      dev.yml
      ...
  role2/
    tasks/
      dev.yml
      ...
```

3) And the task in the playbook(s):

```
- name: Apply every role, but only the teams part
  include_role:
    name: "{{ item.0 }}"
    tasks_from: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ application_role|product(teams)|list }}"
```